# Regex how to match the whole line based on the start of the line?

Tags: c#, regex

So I have the SQL file and I want to find the setvars.
The file looks like this:

```
...  
:setvar DatabaseName "Database_1"  
...  
:setvar DefaultDataPath ""
```

My pattern in this state `"(?m)^:setvar " + variable` where the variable should be for example "DatabasseName" or "DefaultDataPath".  But the end of the line is not in the Value property of the match.
I tried this too: `"(?m)^:setvar " + variable + ".+\"$"` but it's not even match :)

Thanks for any help,
Péter

Comment: You can try this "(?m)^:setvar " + variable + "(.+)$" and then search for the variables in Match.Groups :)

Comment: If you only want to check for matches per line, you could also use `string.Split()` to pre-format the string before trying to match anything.

Comment: Do you need to just check if it's match or you need to get value from a string?

Answer (score 3):

Try `:setvar\s+(?<variable>\w*)\s+"?(?<value>\w*)"?` - this will parse each line and give you a named group containing the variable and the value for every match.

Breaking it down:

- `:setvar` finds a section of the string that starts with ":setvar" followed by one or more spaces.
- `(?<variable>\w*)` takes the non-whitespace characters following that "setvar" and parses them into the named group "variable"
- `"?(?<value>\w*)"?` takes the non-whitespace characters following the variable and parses them into the named group "value". The "? on each side makes the quotes optional.
- `\s+` (which appears several times) allows for one or more spaces to seperate the setvar from the variable and the value.

so using this code:

```
var findSetvars = new Regex(@":setvar\s+(?<variable>\w*)\s+""?(?<value>\w*)""?");
var matches = findSetvars.matches(input);
```

you will get a `MatchCollection` in `matches` that can be enumerated through like so:

```
foreach(Match match in matches)
{
   var variable = match.Groups["variable"];
   var value = match.Groups["value"];
   // now do whatever. 
}
```

Note that the `Regex.MatchCollection` is one of the .net 1.0 style object collections so you have to tell the compiler that each member of it is a `Match` object. Quite annoying, wish they would switch it out for a generic list of matches. The result of `match.Groups["groupname"]` will be the string that was captured by the group.

Comment: Please explain to me what the ? at the end is used for? What's wrong with a pair of ^ and $? Thanks.

Comment: The ? is to make the quotes optional. The ^ and $ are not really needed- if someone puts some extra white space after or before a set of arguments, it would trigger a false negative.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern.

```
(\:setvar)\s+(?<variable_name>\S+)\s+"?(?<variable_value>.*)"?
```

with this input

```
...  
:setvar DatabaseName "Database_1"  
...  
:setvar DefaultDataPath ""  
...
:setvar IntVariable 24
```